# How do I display multiple JPanels with multiple layouts?

Tags: java, jframe, jpanel

I've been working on this project for an assignment and I've been stuck on this problem. I new and don't understand much of the programming jargon so if someone could help explain why my program isn't working that would be great.

The programs purpose is to display a randomly generated matrix of 1's and 0's in a 10x10 layout and have some buttons on the top that have functions. I'm just stock on how to get everything to display.

Thanks in advance.

UPDATE:: Told providing all my code would help

```
public class Module5 extends JFrame {

private static JTextArea area = new JTextArea();
private static JFrame frame = new JFrame();
private static JPanel general = new JPanel();
private static JPanel buttons = new JPanel();
private static JPanel numbers = new JPanel();
private static JButton button0 = new JButton("Reset to 0");
private static JButton button1 = new JButton("Resset to 1");
private static JButton buttonReset = new JButton("Reset");
private static JButton quit = new JButton("Quit");

public static class Numbers extends JPanel {

    public Numbers() {
        area.setText(Integer.toString((int) Math.round(Math.random())));
        this.add(area);
    }    

    public void Module5(){

        numbers.setLayout(new GridLayout(10, 10));
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            this.add(new Numbers());
        }
    }
}

public static void main (String[] args) {

    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(300, 300);
    frame.setVisible(true);

    general.setLayout(new BoxLayout(general, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
    general.add(buttons);
    general.add(numbers);

    buttons.add(button0);
    buttons.add(button1);
    buttons.add(buttonReset);

    buttons.add(quit);
    quit.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            System.exit(0);
        }
    });
}
```

}

Comment: Please include the rest of your code, i.e. the definitions of `general`, `buttons` etc. This will help us determine what the problem is.

Comment: @JavaDevil made sure to add everything, thanks for the help

Comment: You're never adding your `general` JPanel to the `frame`.
Insert `frame.setContentPane(general);` and you will see your buttons. - that should get you started. Since this an assignment, don't expect too much help writing the whole program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this does look like homework I'll give you some pointers but am not going to give you the code.

1. Move your constructor for `Module5` out of the numbers class and into its own class. Also remove the `void` return type from this to make it a correct constructor.
2. Move the code in your main into the constructor for `Module5`. This is the main frame so when you build a new one it should be initialised here, not in main. And remove the `setVisible` call for now (this is addressed in number 6)
3. After doing 1 and 2, get rid of your `frame` variable, your `Module5` is a `JFrame` so anything to do with `frame` can just be changed to the keyword `this` (meaning this `Module5` object)
4. Also move the `area` variable to be within the `Numbers` class - otherwise every `Number` is essentially going to share the same text area and This is not what you want.
5. Don't have your variables as `static` they should not need to be.
6. Once this is all done make sure it is running on the Event Dispatch Thread by making your main method like this (the one piece of code I will give you)

   ```
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
       SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
       {
           @Override
           public void run()
           {
               Module5 mod5 = new Module5();
               mod5.setVisible(true);
           }
       });
   }
   ```